# Remove from HashSet with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary of string and HashSet of string and want to remove the ones elements that have the other and visa versa:

here is working example

```
var squad = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

foreach (var curr in squad.Keys)
{
      foreach (var creature in squad.Keys)
      {
          if (squad[curr].Contains(creature)
               && squad[creature].Contains(curr))
          {
               squad[curr].Remove(creature);
               squad[creature].Remove(curr);
          }
      }
}
```

how to do this with Linq?

**Here is the Input**

```
Mozilla -> Tony
Tony -> Godzilla
Mozilla -> Dony
Tony -> Franzilla
Mozilla -> Mony
Tony -> Mozilla
Blaze it!
```

**Here is the Output**

```
Mozilla : 2
Tony : 2
```

the whole code:

```
namespace SoftUni
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class PhoenixOscarRomeoNovember
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var squadInfo = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "Blaze it!") break;

                var tokens = input
                    .Split(new string[] {" -> "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                var creature = tokens[0];
                var squadMate = tokens[1];

                if (creature == squadMate)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (squadInfo.ContainsKey(creature))
                {
                    if (squadInfo[creature].Contains(squadMate))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    squadInfo[creature].Add(squadMate);
                }
                else
                {
                    squadInfo.Add(creature, new HashSet<string>() { squadMate });
                }
            }

            foreach (var curr in squadInfo.Keys)
            {
                foreach (var creature in squadInfo.Keys)
                {
                    if (squadInfo[curr].Contains(creature)
                        && squadInfo[creature].Contains(curr))
                    {
                        squadInfo[curr].Remove(creature);
                        squadInfo[creature].Remove(curr);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var creature in squadInfo.OrderByDescending(b => b.Value.Count))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{creature.Key} : {creature.Value.Count}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well just like Linq and I am interested to know if there is a way to change something of this in Linq or just make it in smarter/better way?

Comment: I think you need to give an example input data and your expected output.

Comment: In general mutating a collection is not what Linq is best for.  Transforming one into another, but not mutating the original.

Comment: Okay I just added the whole code with input/output

Answer (score 1):

I cannot figure out what this code is supposed to do.

While the sample data & output may make sense to you, changing the input to just the one entry of `Mozilla -> Dony` yields `Mozilla : 1`, which doesn't fit with your description of it's purpose.

In any event, your question is about LINQ & using it to remove elements.

That is a basic misunderstanding of LINQs underlying paradigm.

Firstly, LINQ is based on `IEnumerable`, which is a read-only forward-only iterator.
You cannot remove items from an iterator.

Secondly, LINQ is a functional programming paradigm. A LINQ query represent an immutable projection of a sequence. That word, 'immutable', is very important in functional programming. You are thinking imperatively, you have a sequence, which you want to mutate, by removing items, and then use the new mutated sequence. Functional programming says mutating that seqeunce is bad, so rather project a new sequence from the original, and then use the projected sequence. You would still achieve the same output, but your original sequence would be intact at the end.